# Porting a spring+Blazeds+flex app -cofused in choosing a complete server side(vaadin/Gwt etc) or html5 and JS based approach

Tags: javascript, html, spring-mvc, vaadin, web-frameworks

We have a Web application which is written in Spring+BlazeDs and Flex. Since flex is involved, it needs an plugin download and does not work on mobile devices.
We want to rewrite the application with following goals:

1. We do not want to change server side code -we have transaction
   services, security, aspects and many features leveraged from Spring
   and is quite stable. It has been written in a very decoupled manner
   and only data is send over to Flex to work upon -so changing UI
   should not require any change in server side
2. It should work across devices, iPads, Tablets, Mobile and PC
3. Flex provides very rich UI -user should get similar experience
4. Easy to learn, use and maintain -yes, this is one of primary requirements as we have
   short cycle for supporting the Mobile apps
5. Separation of UI and Core server logic

Our team background: Mostly java background (who 'learned' flex), little exposure to JavaScript frameworks and HTML5.
Some evaluation :

1. Framework like Vaadin/JSF/Wicket which have "everything" at server side -even the UI. Our primary concern 
   a.> Ui code and server code will get mixed up. If we want some UI designer to work independently on components -not sure how it will end up! Do they provide such rich set of components that This might not be required at all? 
   b.> Will it work across browser
2. HTML5 and JS frameworks as Angular
   a.>Even with Aptana and webstorm IDE, coding and debugging in JavaScript seems challenging -may be because we all are not that experiences there
   b.>I saw Vaadin sampler page and it provides really rich set of UI component and seems to be a RAD model in true sense .. do we have similar frameworks for html and js?

We went through resources on Web, nice comparison of Java based web frameworks http://zeroturnaround.com/rebellabs/the-curious-coders-java-web-frameworks-comparison-spring-mvc-grails-vaadin-gwt-wicket-play-struts-and-jsf/9/ But we are confused with the strategy -A complete server side framework or Server(SpringMvc)+HTML5+JS kind of framework.

I an inclined towards a vaadin based approach -if it supports mobile devices out of box and provides a really rich UI and theme that custom development might not be needed at all -Both of these can be validated by some one having long term experience with vaadin

==May be I should narrow down my question -does vaadin supports all devices (ipad/mobile) ..etc of box and runs in any given browser seamlessly?

Comment: This is one of these "It depends" questions... Vaadin has the advantage you don't have to know and Debug JS. The business logic is on the server side (which is also security gain) You don't have to worry about client<->server communication, XSS etc. attacks. What could be a drawback is the fact that offline mode is at the moment very limited (But they are improving there)...

Comment: Does vaadin supports all devices (ipad/mobile) ..etc of box and runs in any given browser seamlessly? or do I need to code separately for that?

Comment: Vaadin runs smooth on mobiles too, you don't need to do special coding for them. BUT: You probably need some adaptations to your application for very small screens and for touch input. (Somthing you need to do in all frameworks) For this you can use the vaadin touchkit which provides mobile widgets. Go to https://vaadin.com/de/demo and look a the mobile mail demo from you mobile phone. Browser compatibility can be found here https://vaadin.com/de/features (Vaadin 6 supports IE6+, Vaadin 7 IE8+)